# Is there any system animation for this menu icon to cross icon transition?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

This is the menu animation Apple uses on it mobile site. I would like to implement it in my app, as it looks cool. Has anyone recreated this/ is there an builtin option to do this?

to elaborate: I want this animation to get triggered when the left navigation bar item is tapped to reveal a crossover modal segue.

Optionally, what would be the best practice to make this.

[image: animation]

Comment: I would use frames to implement it   Or you can use Quatz Core generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [FRDLivelyButton](https://github.com/sebastienwindal/FRDLivelyButton). It has the functionality that you are looking for.